# Stacked Widget in PyQt5 does not takes full main window space

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I created a Main Window in PyQt5 with stacked widget.
I want this stacked widget to cover entire window but this is what I am getting:
[image]
You can see stacked widget is not taking entire window it has a small border around it.
Expected output:[image]
The difference between two images is the border around my stacked widget.
Is there any solution to this problem? If I am missing something or question is not clear than comment, also if you down vote please comment reason for down vote. Thanks

EDIT:
I tried to make to make Central Widget's Layout margin to be 0 through QT-Designer. It seems to work fine for left, right and top side but at bottom I am getting this:[image]
If you focus towards bottom right you will notice there are two triangles made of dots. I think one of them is extra, how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm coming from Qt/C++ but maybe try a `mainWindow.setContentsMargin(0, 0, 0, 0)`? `self.setContentMargin(...)`? [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setContentsMargins).

Comment: Hey I checked out the link you posted. According to answer there, I had to make my central widgets layout margin as 0. I did that and if works perfect for top, down and left side but on bottom I am getting undesirable result. I will post the image in edit

Comment: That's the status bar, I think? Try setting the visibility of mainWindow.statusBar to false.

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to achieve this through Qt Designer. I am unable to achieve it through code

Comment: Hey thank you so much it worked. I managed to find code to hide status bar. Anyway my main question was about margin and not status bar so I will mark this question duplicate. Thank you! Anyway how do i mark this duplicate? There was a option available before on top but now its gone